# Buffersize when using x-terminal-emulator

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Does anyone know how to configure the x-terminal-emulator so that I can increase the buffer/scroll back size of the window in ubuntu ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`x-terminal-emulator` is just a wrapper. On my version of Ubuntu, it in fact runs `gnome-terminal`, which could be configured via "Edit" -> "Profile Preferences" -> "Scrolling".